# Convert dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/YYYY

Tags: c#, date-formatting, date-conversion

I need to convert "28/08/2012" to `MM/dd/YYYY` format that means "08/28/2012".
How can I do that?

I am using below code , but it threw exception to me.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("28/08/2012", "ddMMyyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> but it threw exception to me

**Problem:**

Your date contains `/` seperator (`"28/08/2012"`) and you are not giving that in your date string format (`"ddMMyyyy"`).

**Solution:**

It should be `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

This way

```
DateTime.ParseExact("28/08/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

After doing that we will receive a DateTime object with your populated dates which is transferred to string using `.ToString()` with desired date format `"MM/dd/yyyy"` and optional culture info `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: I want to retrivr format in String

Comment: Yeah that's what this will do. First it will convert this into DateTime and then back into string

Comment: @LajjaThaker: Read updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since your original date is in `en-GB` culture, you can create a `CultureInfo` object and parse your `DateTime` naturally.

```
string date = "28/08/2012";
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
Convert.ToDateTime(date,ci.DateTimeFormat).ToString("d");//short date pattern
```

(OR)

```
DateTime.Parse(date,ci.DateTimeFormat).ToString("d");
```