# How can I modify a form field value during form submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a form using ASP.NET form controls. One of the form fields is Date of Birth. The date format is in dd/mm/yyyy. What I need to do is actually convert this form field to mm/dd/yyyy once the user submits the form but before the data goes to the server because the system the form data is going to is forcing US date formats (mm/dd/yyyy) which I can't control, hence all date formats in dd/mm/yyyy will be reversed so they will be incorrect. So I need to actually switch it before hand, so its actually reversed back to the correct format. Here's what I've wrote in order to switch the value.

```
string userDOB = Request.Form["txtDOB2"];
DateTime convertedDOB = Convert.ToDateTime(userDOB);
txtDOB2.Text = convertedDOB.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Note: I am checking to make sure the Date of Birth field not null or empty etc, just posting the specific code related to my question.

I'm running this in code behind via a submit button click action. So far, a test label just appends the switched date format value to confirm its working. However I'm unsure how to switch the form value itself so it ends up in the actual posted form data. Request.Form is read only, so I don't know how to assign the modified date to the form field value.

Another potential problem is the form action is to an external source, outside of the domain the form is running on.

Comment: you can use jquery datepicker http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. Here you can enforce the dateformat so it wont change other than the prescribed format.

Comment: try to use DateTime.ParseExact("28/08/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: check this link, it may be helpful to you. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328381/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: [this article](http://valuetype.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/javascript-compare-two-dates/) might be useful to check date

Comment: @Professor I don't want to force a date format entirely. I need it to be dd/mm/yyyy to the user, but then I need to adjust it server side because of the forced US date format from the server the form data is going to.

Comment: @Himanshu This seems like what I'm looking for, how can I assign the updated date format to the txtDOB2 form field though? That's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: As an aside, I'd solve this on the server (using some kind of intervention). Otherwise this is going to be a perpetual problem with the likely hood of forgetting a UI instance you did not correct [not to mention a dependency on the JS you write to correct it])

Comment: @BradChristie I totally agree, however I can't solve it as its an external system out of my control. I wouldn't use JS for this however, I'm thinking server side, hence asp.net c#

Comment: @James: How about using an [`IHttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing everything I've decided to use a WebRequest:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

With the form action being an external URL (not on the same domain) I have come to the conclusion I am unable to modify the form data. However, by allowing the form to postback and specifying the form action and everything else in code behind I'm able to specify the DOB value to send, using Himanshu's DOB conversion method, I was able to POST a form with the DOB switched.

Answer (score 0):

This would be how I'd attack it:

**FormatDatesModule.cs**

```
public class FormatDatesModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static readonly Regex dateFilter = new Regex(@"^(?<d>\d{2})\/(?<m>\d{2})\/(?<y>\d{4})$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += (sender,e) => {
            HttpRequest request = ((HttpApplication)sender).Request;

            if (request.QueryString.Count > 0)
            {
                this.FormatDatesInCollection(request.QueryString);
            }

            if (request.HttpMethod == "POST" && request.Form.Count > 0)
            {
                this.FormatDatesInCollection(request.Form);
            }
        };
    }

    private static void FormatDatesInCollection(NameValueCollection parameters)
    {
        // Bypass readonly
        PropertyInfo isReadOnly = parameters.GetType().GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        isReadOnly.SetValue(parameters, false, null);

        for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            Match dateMatch = dateFilter.Match(parameters[i]);
            if (dateMatch.Success)
            {
                parameters[i] = String.Join("/", dateMatch.Groups["m"].Value, dateMatch.Groups["d"].Value, dateMatch.Groups["y"].Value);
            }
        }

        isReadOnly.SetValue(parameters, true, null);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="FormatDatesModule" type="FormatDatesModule"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer> <!-- IIS 7 Integrated Mode -->
        <modules>
            <add name="FormatDatesModule" type="FormatDatesModule"/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think a programmatic approach is going to be the best way here. The form action is external so it might the only way to post form data the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code on button click event.
for e.g

```
    textBox1.Text="31/03/2014"
```

then

```
   Button_click()
   {
        DateTime MyDateTime = new DateTime();
        MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
        textBox2.Text = MyDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
   }
```

OR Directly you can use

```
   textBox2.Text=(DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy",null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

First you have to Convert it to DateTime format, then again in string. Hope that would be helpful for you.

Comment: This works but only when the ASP.NET form action is itself i.e. postback. The form action is to external source, so once the form gets submitted the new date value is lost. Apologies I should of mentioned this before.

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting your problem, if you are worried about data lost you can save that data in a variable(like string) and further use that variable.

Comment: As the form action for the form is an external URL (not posting back to self), the converted DOB variable isn't getting sent in the form data. Instead, I've had use a WebRequest to send the data, which from there I can specify the DOB variable which is converted to MM/DD/YYYY.